# Does the sun have both types of angular momentum?

Tags: orbital-motion, sun, solar-system

Does the sun have both types of angular momentum, 1. spin angular momentum 2. orbital angular momentum?

Comment: What do you mean by spin angular momentum, do you mean classically or are you thinking in quantum terms, and if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the answer. The spin was a concept I was referring in classical terms. I did not think about quantum mechanical concept of spin. So I think it would be wise to drop the usage of the word spin from spin angular momentum. When the sun rotates on its own axis it is angular momentum. The sun rotates on its axis once every 27 days. The spin I refer to is the sun rotating on its axis. So instead of using the term spin angular momentum we can simply say that the sun rotates on its axis and that simply refers to "Angular Momentum".

Also the sun orbits the centre of galaxy this is "Orbital Angular Momentum".  It takes the Sun 226 million years to completely orbit around the center of the Milky Way.

Comment: "Angular momentum" is more general, you could use the term 'rotation' or 'rotational angular momentum' to specify the "spinning" motion.

Answer (score 2):

Classically, the total angular momentum of any body with reference to an arbitrary reference point can always be considered to be the vector sum of the spin angular momentum with reference to its center of gravity and the orbital angular momentum with reference to this arbitrary reference point. Thus, in general, the sun has both a spin angular momentum due to its rotation and an orbital angular momentum which depends on the point of reference.

If you take this point of reference to be the center of gravity of our milky way, then the orbital angular momentum is due to the rotational movement of the sun in our galaxy.If you take this point of reference to be the center of gravity of our solar system, then the orbital angular momentum is due to the movement of the center of gravity of the sun around the center of gravity of the solar system.

Answer (score 0):

The sun is rotating on it's axis, rotating about its common center of mass with Jupiter (with the other planets too, but those effects are small compared to Jupiter) and rotating about the center of the galaxy.

Spin is a quantum concept, inspired by the idea of a sphere spinning about its center, but isn't actually the angular momentum associated with spinning material.  One key difference between spin and ordinary angular momentum is that a spin-1/2 particle (like an electron) must go through two revolutions to get back to the original state (a little bit like a Mobius Strip).

It turns out that neither spin nor orbital angular momentum are conserved on their own, we need both to have a fully conserved quantity.

That being said, if the magnetic field of sun is strong enough (I really don't know if it is) it could polarize the plasma that makes up the sun and result in an overall net spin.  The competing processes are the high temperatures (which would tend to erase any polarization), and strong magnetic fields (which would tend to polarize the plasma).

A quick search gave this result.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7773358/?reload=true

Which looks promising, but I haven't read it carefully yet.

Comment: While there is a quantum mechanical concept called 'spin' I don't see how it is relevant here. The angular momentum is the sun spinning (rotating)  on its axis which is a perfectly normal classical phenomenon. QM spin derives its name from being analagous to this

Comment: In physics-land, if you talk about 'spin', you are usually talking about the quantum concept.  From the question, it's hard to know which sense of the word 'spin' he was using, so I covered both possibilities.  That's why my first paragraph mentioned all the kinds of angular momentum, that the sun is involved with, including rotating about its own axis.  In this way, I was hoping to untangle the usage of 'spin' and not worry about confusing different ideas.

Comment: Spin is *not* exclusive to quantum mechanics; it describes any angular momentum which is independent of the coordinate origin and it works equally well in classical mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

If by this you mean: does the Sun rotate as a rigid body the answer is certainly no, as you can read [in this article](http://www.windows2universe.org/sun/Solar_interior/Sun_layers/differential_rotation.html).  BTW this article clearly refers to spin (in a non-quantum way of course) as internal angular momentum.

In addition [some vortex flows have been observed](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/593329/fulltext/23303.text.html); the internal and bulk rotational structure of the Sun is quite complicated (much to the delight of heliophysicists I might add).

Comment: I would say that is a good explation, but I have no idea what you said

Answer (score -3):

Sun is a classical system, so we don't expect any quantum correlations. If any, the sun has a negligible spin in comparison with its angular momentum. The spin of the Sun is a sum of spins of all particles that constitute the sun, and this sum will be of the order of $\hbar$, because most of the spin will cancel.

Comment: What?  Spin exists macroscopically... not just as a quantum property

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Then I suggest that you start to rewrite Wikipedia articles, starting from this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)

Comment: An article which includes a disclaimer at the top "This article is about spin in quantum mechanics. For rotation in classical mechanics, see angular momentum." to clarify it is talking about quantum spin rather than any classical concept of spinning objects.

Comment: @PhillS It is exactly as in a disclaimer that you quoted; the clasical concept of spinning objects is called angular momentum. Spin is a pure quantum mechanical concept. In classical physics, point-like particles cannot have any intrinsic angular momentum. Classical spinning object has angular momentum and does not have spin.